# How to Clear Table Style in Office Scripts?

Tags: excel, typescript, office-scripts

How can I clear the styles on a table? I tried recording the macro but when I record it and run it, it will say failed (Table setPredefinedTableStyle: The argument is invalid or missing or has an incorrect format.).

```
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
  let selectedSheet = workbook.getActiveWorksheet();
  let mainTable = selectedSheet.getTable("MainTable");
  mainTable.setPredefinedTableStyle("undefined");
}
```

How can I clear the table style?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office-scripts/excelscript/excelscript.table?view=office-scripts#setpredefinedtablestyle-predefinedtablestyle-

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Excel tables in web always has a style. There isn't a way to clear all styles.
There doesn't appear to be a way to assign the "none" style, which is the most basic style. I'll follow-up on that.

[image]

The closest I can get to was to use `TableStyleLight1` style as shown below.

```js
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
  let selectedSheet = workbook.getActiveWorksheet();
  let mainTable = selectedSheet.getTable("MainTable");
  mainTable.setPredefinedTableStyle('TableStyleLight1')
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Set the predefined table style to 'null' and it'll clear the table style. I found it while I was looking for a PAD + PA + Office Scripts flow

`newTable.setPredefinedTableStyle(null);`

Comment: Great answer. I think part of the reason this isn't discoverable is that the Office Scripts TS types and tsconfig aren't null-safe, so `predefinedTableStyle`'s parameter is listed as `string` when it's actually `string | null`.